# Ember.Select what is the correct OptionValuePath and OptionLabelPath?

Tags: ember.js

example here
http://jsfiddle.net/tobikko/ysFC6/10/

how do i really find out what to put in for OptionValuePath and OptionLabelPath? as you can see the dropdown is there with a list but the values are not visible.

in this case i know that it should be OptionLabelPath: "content.firstName" but what if i didn't know?

i created the focusOut function to examine the content of the view and it looks like this
[image: content]

in my real app that i'm having problem with, each object in the content doesn't contain the **ember1340135889380_meta object or the __proto** part. is that the problem? how do i fix it?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.SelectView }}

  <p>Selected: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.fullName}}
    (ID: {{App.selectedPersonController.person.id}})</p>
</script>
```

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.SelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentBinding: "App.peopleController",
    selectionBinding: "App.selectedPersonController.person",
    optionLabelPath: "firstName",
    optionValuePath: "id",
    prompt: "select",

  focusOut: function () {
        var test = this.get('content');
   }  
})


App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName').cacheable()
});

App.selectedPersonController = Ember.Object.create({
    person: null
});


App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Yehuda',
        lastName: 'Katz'},
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Tom',
        lastName: 'Dale'},
    {
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'Peter',
        lastName: 'Wagenet'},
    {
        id: 4,
        firstName: 'Erik',
        lastName: 'Bryn'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/fe22710101954fb1b9b8af2df4dc294f125f59b7/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js#L33-51), you always have to prepend `content.` to the path of the property which shall be used as `id` and `label`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/B2rJN/.

Your mentioned `ember1340135889380_meta` and similar properties on an object indicate that it's an instance of an `Ember.Object`. But the entries in the `Ember.Select`'s `content` do not need to be an instance of an `Ember.Object`, the path also works for "normal" objects, as you use in your example.

---

***Background***:

The `Ember.View` is basically rendered as follows:

```
<select>
  {{#if view.prompt}}
    <option value>{{view.prompt}}</option>
  {{/if}}
  {{#each view.content}}
    {{view Ember.SelectOption contentBinding="this"}}
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

So in the each-iteration the current item is made available to the `Ember.SelectOption` view via `content` as well. That's why you have to prepend `content.` when you specify the path to the `id` / `label` property. Makes sense?

Comment: yes that makes sense. but it is not working like that in my real app. i have a couple of Ember.Select one is working and one is not and the only difference i can tell is the content type. so i'm stump. :(

Comment: What do you mean by content type? Can you provide a JSFiddle or show some code? In general: if you have a property x you want to use as `id` or `label` prepend it with `content`, so it's `content.x`.